# How to create deep copy of array passed, if the array is valid?

Tags: java, arrays

SO an IPv4 array is passed to this method, and if valid, creates a deep copy of the array in the instance variable "parts"

```
/**
 * If the ip address from the array passed (data) is valid,
 * makes a deep copy of the array passed in the instance variable parts.
 * For example, if data = {192,168,0,1}, parts should become {192,168,0,1}
 * by copying each item of data into corresponding item in parts.
 * If the ip address passed is invalid (for example {500,4,60,216}
 * or {192,16,01}, or {13,13,13,13,13}, parts should become {0,0,0,0}
 * 
 * remember to reset the instance array parts before you do anything else
 * @param data
 */
public void setParts(int[] data) {
this.parts = new int[4];
if (data.length != 4){
    parts = new int[]{0,0,0,0};
}
else
    for (int i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
        if ((data[i] < 0) || (data[i] > 255))
            parts = new int[]{0,0,0,0};
        else
            parts[i] = data[i];
}
```

is all I have so far. What could I be missing?

EDIT: made one simple change:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
```

And a JUnit test

```
    public void testSetPartsIntArray() {
    correct1.setParts(new int[]{12, 14, 16, 18});
    int[] a = correct1.getParts();
    assertEquals(4, a.length);
    assertEquals(12, a[0]);
    assertEquals(14, a[1]);
    assertEquals(16, a[2]);
    assertEquals(18, a[3]); 

    correct1.setParts(new int[]{-12, 14, 16, 18});
    a = correct1.getParts();
    assertEquals(4, a.length);
    assertEquals(0, a[0]);
    assertEquals(0, a[1]);
    assertEquals(0, a[2]);
    assertEquals(0, a[3]);
```

works UNTIL

```
assertEquals(0, a[1]);
```

What is causing it to stop there?

Comment: What is the problem with what you have??

Comment: @Guy sorry I have added an edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you find an invalid value, you must break from the loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
    if ((data[i] < 0) || (data[i] > 255)) {
        parts = new int[]{0,0,0,0};
        break;
    } else {
        parts[i] = data[i];
    }
```

In your failed case, the first element `-12` is invalid, so `parts` is set to `new int[]{0,0,0,0}`, but then you continue the loop, and since the rest of the numbers are valid, you end up with `{0, 14, 16, 18}` instead of `{0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Answer (score 2):

Eran solved your direct problem, but please note: your are still using **bad** abstractions, and your design should be improved around the following aspects:

1. Do **not** use an array of int to represent an IP address. Java has [INetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) for this purpose. There is **no** sense in using a 4-member array to represent that information. You see, you are restricting yourself to IPv4. 4 ints wont do for IPv6. So you would have to throw all of that away when somebody asks you to work with IPv6!
2. You are mixing up responsibilities. It seems that setParts() is used to setup a field *parts* in your class. But in reality, that method does **valide input** and **setting**. And worse: if the incoming address is invalid, you don't notice. Well, you override the array elements to be all 0 then, but the address resulting out of that 0.0.0.0 is still invalid! So you will need checks all over the place to ensure that your address is really valid. Don't do that. It would be better to A) separate validation of input from setting of your field and B) not **allow** your field *parts* to represent an invalid IP address.

You see, if you would be using the INetAddress class, and you would be passing a string with an "invalid" address; that class would throw an exception. And that is actually **better** than silently turning something into 0.0.0.0.

Because there are no good reasons to say "this thing here means X; but well, for convenience, we also allow it to mean 'broken X'". Simply: don't do that. Your application becomes much more **robust** when you don't allow "invalid" data to hang around. Otherwise, as said; every piece of code dealing with *parts* must be prepared that it is 0.0.0.0. So you need error handling for that ... all over the place!

And finally: what if there is a typo somewhere. Somebody wanted to pass 128.192.168.1, but typed 128.912.168.1. Shouldn't that user better be told that he provided unexpected input?!

Comment: Would you mind explaining more on  the one bad index thing? 
As for passing IP addresses as array of ints, this is for an assignment, and that was just the specs we were given lol

Comment: I got interrupted ;-) ... you got an answer in the meantime, but I still suggest that you rework major parts of your code. See my updates.